# How would I calculate the runtime of this function?

Tags: c++

I have this function written in C++ and I am trying to calculate the runtime of it. I believe the runtime is O(n^2) (I attempt to explain why using comments in the code), but I was looking for confirmation.

```
    void f1(int n)
    {
    int t = sqrt(n);
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){              //this outer for loop by itself has a runtime of O(n) but decreases by sqrt(n) every time it goes back to the top
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){          //this inner for loop has a run time of O(n) but decreases by sqrt(n) every time it goes back to the top of the function
            // do something O(1)
        }
        n -= t;                             
      }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about your edits, surely you want to rollback to version 1 of this question?

Comment: The edit has removed the code and without that the question is quite incomplete. Please revert your edit or update your question

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume this is `sqrt()` from `cmath` header. The function returns a double precision value `t` such that `round(t * t) == n`.

Let's estimate the number of operations:

- On the first iteration of the outer loop the inner loop performs `n` iterations.
- On the second iteration of the outer loop the inner loop performs `n - t` iterations,
- and so on...

The number of iterations of the outer loop would be between `t` and `t + 1` as `t * t` might be less than `n`.

So to calculate the total number of iterations of the inner loop we have to calculate the following summation:

```
n + (n - t) + (n - 2*t) + ... + (n - t * t) = 
n * t - t * (1 + 2 + ... + t) = 
n * t - t * t * (t + 1) / 2 = 
t * t * t - t * t * (t + 1) / 2 =
t^3/2 - t^2/2  = O(n^(3/2))
```

Comment: `t*(1+2+.. +t)`.. shouldn't this be `t*t*(t+1)/2` and effectively resulting in `n*sqrt(n)/2`?